# How can i add Bad word filter in this form function (if bad word exist it wont submit)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is the script i tried it worked and gives alert but at last form gets submitted i want to stop that if bad word exist in the textarea . the form should not get submitted and the people get the alert function.. im using CODEIGNITOR framework.

JAVSCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var swear_words_arr=new Array("fuck","kill","ugly");

var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;
function reset_alert_count()
{
 swear_alert_count=0;
}
function validate_text()
{
 reset_alert_count();
 var compare_text=document.form1.msg_text.value;
 for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++)
 {
  for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
  {
   if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
   {
    swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
    swear_alert_count++;
   }
  }
 }
 var alert_text="";
 for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
 {
  alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
 }
 if(swear_alert_count>0)
 {
  alert("The message will not be sent!!!\nThe following illegal words were found:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
  document.form1.msg_text.select();
 }
 else
 {
  document.form1.submit();
 }
}
function select_area()
{
 document.form1.msg_text.select();
}
window.onload=reset_alert_count;
    </script>
```

is there any possible to convert this in the php function.

MODEL FUNCTION:

```
    public function create_msg($msg_text, $user_id){

        $data = array(
            'msg_text' => $msg_text,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );

        if( $this->db->insert('swall_message', $data) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
   }
```

TEXTAREA CODE:

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url('user/'.$user->user_uid);?>" method="POST" name="form1">
   
   

<div class="form-group">



    <textarea name="msg_text" onClick="select_area()" cols="30"  class="form-control" rows="5" minlength="1" maxlength="5000" required=""></textarea>
    
    
    
    
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->user_id;?>">
</div>
 <div class="col-12">
                                    <label class="custom-label"><?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;?></label>
                                </div>



<button type="submit" onClick="validate_text();" class="btn btn-block text-uppercase">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: TL;DR, why are you trying to filter out bad words with JavaScript? You know your clients could alter that filter and therefore even remove it? You cant stop people from submitting this form with bad words in it. You could however on the server side (PHP) not allow to save the values and display an error message.

Comment: There is also this problem that is not a free coding service. Simply (before saving) loop through your bad word array and if the message contains one of those values then simply abort saving and show an error message (and maybe even reload the data they tried to send so they can change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Filter data in php code**

This code is untested. Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

```
<?php

$msg_text = 'fuck';
 $data = array(
            'msg_text' => $msg_text,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );
$swear_words_arr=array("fuck","kill","ugly");

if(in_array($data['msg_text'], $swear_words_arr)){
    echo "failed";
    return false;

}

// else this is true. your db code below

echo "passed";

return true;

?>
```

Comment: you need to look into CI documentation depending on the version you use, how to redirect back.

Comment: One problem with this code is that only if we type one word then only this function words for example when i tried puting like ugly and it worked but if i type 'ugly people" the form get submited still why is that THIS IS THE CODE: 'public function 
        
$swear_words_arr=array("fuck","kill","ugly");

if(in_array($data['msg_text'], $swear_words_arr)){
    echo "failed";
    return false;

}else{
$this->db->insert('swall_message', $data);
            return true;
}
       
   }

Comment: Run a for loop on the restricted word array, and look for string position or do regex test with php. Look for strpos or preg_matches in google. You will get correct usage

Answer (score 0):

```js
var swear_words_arr=new Array("fuck","kill","ugly");

function validate_text(event){
const text = document.getElementById("text").value;
console.log(text); // if you see the console, the form submit is stopped.
if(swear_words_arr.indexOf(text) !== -1){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}

return true;

}
```

```html
Try to insert return before the function and use stopPropagation


<form>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<button type="submit" onClick="return validate_text(event);" class="btn btn-block text-uppercase">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you dont want to form to be submitted, you need to do it on javascript. After submit, if you want to filter, you can use in_array php function. Please check my next answer